How do I add a keyboard listener to a compose window in a Thunderbird extension?
I'm writing an extension for Thunderbird email client.
One part of the extension is a character counter when composing new messages. For this I'll ideally need to add a keyboard listener to perform a counting function on keyup.
The alternative is to use a setInterval and just continually perform the counting function every half second or so, but that's obviously not as ideal as just updating the counter on each keypress.
The API documentation says that I can add listeners using .addListener but it doesn't actually explain how to do that, I can't seem to find a way to make it work.
messenger.addEventListener() is not a function.
window.addEventListener() doesn't seem to actually add the listener to the compose window like it would to a browser window.
Also tried document.body but no joy.
Is this even possible?
